# h2o4gpu on windows 7 platform for R

Tags: windows-7, gpu, cran, h2o4gpu

great to see the news about h2o4gpu in R world, but just wondering if there would be an option for folks using windows based environment. Appreciate if you could respond

Answer (score 1):

Currently we don't support Windows but we're considering it. The main constraint is the build process, which we're redoing this week and should make it easier to add Windows support in the future.

Please vote on this issue https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu/issues/517 so we can see what's the demand.

Comment: thank you Mat for your note, appreciate it. Look forward to using the windows version soon.